# Partitioning Dual-Boot on SSD and HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 250GB SSD and a 1TB HDD and I'm trying to Dual-Boot Windows and Ubuntu.

My plan is to install Windows and Ubuntu only on the SSD, and then give half of the HDD to each OS for storing larger files (such as games).

```
In my head I imagine the SSD and HDD to look like this:
SSD:
Windows Boot/OS (125GB) | Ubuntu Boot/OS (125GB)
HDD:
Storage for Windows (500GB) | Storage for Ubuntu (500GB)
```

Is this possible and if so, what are the step-by-step instructions of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
First, save everything you might need from the HDD and SSD.
To make it simpler, install Windows first. If asked, select custom install/setup, and you can select where to install windows. You need to delete every partition, so you can only see the unformatted and unpartitioned drives.
You will now half the storage on each drive, by creating a partition (a 125GB partition on the SSD, and a 500gb partition on the HDD), and format them. Leave the free space for ubuntu unpartitioned, and carry on installing Windows.
After it is installed, install Ubuntu. Select custom installation as well, and you can format the space for Linux here.

After Linux is installed, you may want to start GParted and label each partition with a name, as there will be 5 partitions seen by Ubuntu, and shown in the file explorer. Identify them according to 
On the SSD:
The partition for windows (125GB, NTFS filesystem)
The boot partition for windows (100MB, NTFS)
And the partition for Ubuntu (~125GB, has ext4 filesystem)
(Note that there may be a separate partition as the children of the 500GB Ubuntu partition, with "Swap" as the filesystem, but you can ignore this because it won't show up normally in the file browser
On the HDD:
The windows partition for games (500GB, NTFS filesystem)
And Ubuntu partition for games (500GB, ext4 filesystem)

After labeling them, mount them (if they weren't mounted by default) and open the file explorer, to see if they show up by the labels you gave them

Comment: To clarify for the end of the first paragraph. Would I simply select the free space of 125GB on the SSD and install Ubuntu onto that, or do I need to manually create the needed partitions for Ubuntu to properly install onto that free space?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible but you will have to install windows first then Ubuntu. What you can do is just simply mount the partition after the installation of both O.S is finished , in Windows you will se that the hard disk will be visible in This PC where as in Ubuntu it will be unmounted first so you will have to mount it and then while installing games you can just choose the default destination where you want to install the games, in windows it is just so simple.

Check out this video https://youtu.be/qMo8krAJd5Q

Comment: "So simple", can we see some more explicit details on the partition scheme to use?

Comment: You should check out this video, I guess this will help you ... https://youtu.be/qMo8krAJd5Q

Comment: I didn't remember how I do it, but I'm able to access at my windows file with my ubuntu 16.04, so I think you can use the totality of your HDD for both OS

Comment: Please add more information to your answer. We prefer answers with content rather than pure links.